# JAVA: Hashmap scanner input lookup

Tags: java, hashmap

Im trying to create a classthat will store a table of people's first names and ages, and read people and ages from the console (e.g. Bob 19) and add to the HashMap. After a list of name, age pairs, a name will be entered without an age (e.g. Bob) and the user will terminate their input (ctrl-z).  Print out the age of the person entered last, or print "unknown" if an age hasnt been entered for them. so for example if i entered "mary 12, bob 10, jon 20, bob" it should return 10.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hashmap {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.next();
            nameArray.add(name);
            Integer age = in.nextInt();
            names.put(name, age);
        }
        Integer value;
        int x = nameArray.size(); 
        value = names.get(x);  
        System.out.println("the age is:" + value); 

    } 
}
```

thanks for the help. I am a Java beginner and appreciate it all

Answer (score 0):

Move name variable declaration out of `while` and get the `age` using the last `name` entered. Here you go:

```
    String name 
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        name = in.next();
        nameArray.add(name);
        Integer age = in.nextInt();
        names.put(name, age);
    }
    Integer value;
    value = names.get(name);  
    System.out.println("the age is:" + value);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but this solution will just output the last complete input i gave to the hashmap. For example if i entered (jon 12, mary 13, jon) i would want it to look at the last input "jon" and lookup in the hashmap to return 12.